# reinterpret_cast between char* and std::uint8_t* - safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing, uint8t

Now we all sometimes have to work with binary data. In C++ we work with sequences of bytes, and since the beginning `char` was the our building block. Defined to have `sizeof` of 1, it is the byte. And all library I/O functions use `char` by default. All is good but there was always a little concern, a little oddity that bugged some people - the number of bits in a byte is implementation-defined.

So in C99, it was decided to introduce several typedefs to let the developers easily express themselves, the fixed-width integer types. Optional, of course, since we never want to hurt portability. Among them, `uint8_t`, migrated into C++11 as `std::uint8_t`, a fixed width 8-bit unsigned integer type, was the perfect choice for people who really wanted to work with 8 bit bytes.

And so, developers embraced the new tools and started building libraries that expressively state that they accept 8-bit byte sequences, as `std::uint8_t*`, `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` or otherwise.

But, perhaps with a very deep thought, the standardization committee decided not to require implementation of `std::char_traits<std::uint8_t>` therefore prohibiting developers from easily and portably instantiating, say, `std::basic_fstream<std::uint8_t>` and easily reading `std::uint8_t`s as a binary data. Or maybe, some of us don't care about the number of bits in a byte and are happy with it.

But unfortunately, two worlds collide and sometimes you have to take a data as `char*` and pass it to a library that expects `std::uint8_t*`. But wait, you say, isn't `char` variable bit and `std::uint8_t` is fixed to 8? Will it result into a loss of data?

Well, there is an interesting Standardese on this. The `char` defined to hold exactly one byte and byte is the lowest addressable chunk of memory, so there can't be a type with bit width lesser than that of `char`. Next, it is defined to be able to hold UTF-8 code units. This gives us the minimum - 8 bits. So now we have a typedef which is required to be 8 bits wide and a type that is at least 8 bits wide. But are there alternatives? Yes, `unsigned char`. Remember that signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. Any other type? Thankfully, no. All other integral types have required ranges which fall outside of 8 bits.

Finally, `std::uint8_t` is optional, that means that the library which uses this type will not compile if it's not defined. But what if it compiles? I can say with a great degree of confidence that this means that we are on a platform with 8 bit bytes and `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Once we have this knowledge, that we have 8-bit bytes, that `std::uint8_t` is implemented as either `char` or `unsigned char`, can we assume that we can do `reinterpret_cast` from `char*` to `std::uint8_t*` and vice versa? Is it portable?

This is where my Standardese reading skills fail me. I read about safely derived pointers (`[basic.stc.dynamic.safety]`) and, as far as I understand, the following:

```
std::uint8_t* buffer = /* ... */ ;
char* buffer2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);
std::uint8_t buffer3 = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(buffer2);
```

is safe if we don't touch `buffer2`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So, given the following preconditions:

- `CHAR_BIT == 8`
- `std::uint8_t` is defined.

Is it portable and safe to cast `char*` and `std::uint8_t*` back and forth, assuming that we're working with binary data and the potential lack of sign of `char` doesn't matter?

I would appreciate references to the Standard with explanations.

EDIT: Thanks, Jerry Coffin. I'm going to add the quote from the Standard ([basic.lval], §3.10/10):

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> ...
>
> — a char or unsigned char type.

EDIT2: Ok, going deeper. `std::uint8_t` is not guaranteed to be a typedef of `unsigned char`. It can be implemented as *extended unsigned integer type* and extended unsigned integer types are not included in §3.10/10. What now?

Comment: To be honest, you would be hard pressed to find a platform where a `char` is _not_ eight bits made in the last 20-odd years or so.

Comment: I believe it will be unsafe only if you happen to meet a machine without 2's-complement representation, in which case you might get unexpected behaviour. But I would like to see someone who actually *know* the answer.

Comment: There's a bunch of modern machines out there like DSPs that only do 32-bit accesses, Joachim.

Comment: "So, if you have two distinct types which have the same binary representation and one of them falls legible for §3.10/10, does this mean the type type is legible?" -- No. There's nothing in the standard to support that idea, and existing compilers which use the exact same representation for `int` and `long` do already treat these differently and subtly break if a pointer to one is used to access an object of the other type.

Comment: Would `char` having a different endian representation cause you any headaches?  Ie, what if `char` nibbles are in the opposite order to `uint8_t` nibbles, so a `reinterpret_cast<char*>` of the pointers will give different values...

Comment: @FaTony: I'm sorry about repeating myself, (see my comment on Jerry Coffin's answer and references therein), but your sentence "`std::uint8_t` is not guaranteed to be a `typedef` of `char`" suggests that it could be. Actually it cannot. C++11, 18.4.1, says that `uint8_t` is a `typedef` for an unsigned integer type. In addition, 3.9.1/3 defines the unsigned integer types and `char` **is not** one of them, regardless whether it can hold negative values or not. C99 states the same.

Comment: I [asked a question a couple weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138237/when-is-uint8-t-unsigned-char) that contains the answer to yours. Take a look at [R.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16138470/541686), which explains that `uint8_t` does **not** need to have the same representation as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @CassioNeri: Excellent observation. I'm going to edit my Q & A.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I would like to point out that there is also `signed char`, which is distinct from either `char` and `unsigned char`. ;-)

Comment: @CassioNeri While that's true, [most compilers will treat `char` as if it had the same signedness as whichever of the other two `char`s it can store the same values as](http://ideone.com/0Vnhrn), even though it's officially supposed to be "neither".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, let's get truly pedantic. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), [this](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) and [this](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), I'm pretty confident that I understand the intention behind both Standards.

So, doing `reinterpret_cast` from `std::uint8_t*` to `char*` and then dereferencing the resulting pointer is **safe** and **portable** and is explicitly permitted by [[basic.lval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.3).

However, doing `reinterpret_cast` from `char*` to `std::uint8_t*` and then dereferencing the resulting pointer is a violation of **strict aliasing rule** and is **undefined behavior** if `std::uint8_t` is implemented as *extended unsigned integer type*.

However, there are two possible workarounds, first:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::uint8_t, char> ||
    std::is_same_v<std::uint8_t, unsigned char>,
    "This library requires std::uint8_t to be implemented as char or unsigned char.");
```

With this assert in place, your code will not compile on platforms on which it would result in undefined behavior otherwise.

Second:

```
std::memcpy(uint8buffer, charbuffer, size);
```

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) says that `std::memcpy` accesses objects as arrays of `unsigned char` so it is **safe** and **portable**.

To reiterate, in order to be able to `reinterpret_cast` between `char*` and `std::uint8_t*` and work with resulting pointers **portably** and **safely** in a 100% standard-conforming way, the following conditions must be true:

- `CHAR_BIT == 8`.
- `std::uint8_t` is defined.
- `std::uint8_t` is implemented as `char` or `unsigned char`.

On a practical note, the above conditions are true on 99% of platforms and there is likely no platform on which the first 2 conditions are true while the 3rd one is false.

Comment: Which begs the question: why use an integral type to do the job of a character type?

Comment: What question would better be addressed to Standardization committee. I would appreciate a separate integral type that has a guaranteed size of 1 byte and which doesn't have semantics of characters.

Comment: `std::uint8_t` doesn't have to be `unsigned char` for this to be portable: it may be `char`, if `char` is defined to be unsigned on a given implementation. (Don't forget that there are 3 types of `char`, not 2 as for other integral types.)

Comment: Correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: About *"std::uint8_t is implemented as char or unsigned char"*: what if it is implemented as a `signed char`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: @AvivCohn It can't be because `signed char` is signed :P

Comment: Haha, whoops. I see my confusion xD. By the way, can you confirm or correct my understanding of this general matter? SAR allows casting any pointer to `char*` and dereferencing it, but not the other way around. It only allows casting a `char*` to `T` and dereferencing it, if `T` is a character type (even if the *signed-ness is different*). And so if `uint8_t` is defined as either `char` or `unsigned char`, i.e. character types, casting a `char*` to a `uint8_t*` is valid. Correct?

Comment: Also, if the above restrictions are followed, it is logically-correct to `reinterpret_cast` a `char` (from a socket, for example) to a `uint8_t` and then check the numeric value of the `uint8_t`. This is because `reinterpret_cast` does not alter the bit pattern, and so we should get the numeric value as represented by an unsigned byte.

Answer (score 20):

If `uint8_t` exists at all, essentially the only choice is that it's a typedef for `unsigned char` (or `char` if it happens to be unsigned). Nothing (but a bitfield) can represent less storage than a `char`, and the only other type that can be as small as 8 bits is a `bool`. The next smallest normal integer type is a `short`, which must be at least 16 bits.

As such, if `uint8_t` exists at all, you really only have two possibilities: you're either casting `unsigned char` to `unsigned char`, or casting `signed char` to `unsigned char`.

The former is an identity conversion, so obviously safe. The latter falls within the "special dispensation" given for accessing any other type as a sequence of char or unsigned char in §3.10/10, so it also gives defined behavior.

Since that includes both `char` and `unsigned char`, a cast to access it as a sequence of char also gives defined behavior.

Edit: As far as Luc's mention of extended integer types goes, I'm not sure how you'd manage to apply it to get a difference in this case. C++ refers to the C99 standard for the definitions of `uint8_t` and such, so the quotes throughout the remainder of this come from C99.

§6.2.6.1/3 specifies that `unsigned char` shall use a pure binary representation, with no padding bits. Padding bits are only allowed in 6.2.6.2/1, which specifically excludes `unsigned char`. That section, however, describes a pure binary representation in detail -- literally to the bit. Therefore, `unsigned char` and `uint8_t` (if it exists) must be represented identically at the bit level.

To see a difference between the two, we have to assert that some particular bits when viewed as one would produce results different from when viewed as the other -- despite the fact that the two must have identical representations at the bit level.

To put it more directly: a difference in result between the two requires that they interpret bits differently -- despite a direct requirement that they interpret bits identically.

Even on a purely theoretical level, this appears difficult to achieve. On anything approaching a practical level, it's obviously ridiculous.

Comment: That 'dispensation' only works in one direction. Pointer to character type -> pointer to anything that is not a character type can easily lead to code that runs afoul of the so-called aliasing rules.

Comment: Alright, unmarking this as answer. This requires deeper investigation.

Comment: If an implementation provides a (say) `__u8` extended integer type, and uses that for `uint8_t`, even if it has the exact same representation as `unsigned char`, the special exception for accessing any object as `unsigned char` does not extend to `__u8`. An implementation might provide such a type *specifically* so that the optimizer can do a better job by assuming there's no aliasing.

Comment: (Less realistic is that the bit order of `unsigned char` and my hypothetical `__u8` might be reversed. I don't see how the standard prohibits that, but I don't see a reason for an implementation to do so either.)

Comment: I'm of the opinion that going down the level of bits is largely useless when it comes to interpreting the Standard -- AFAICT all the operations are defined in terms of mathematical terms, and e.g. the notion of 'object representation' serves to further handwave away the details, to the point that it's too disconnected from the value representation. (I heartily agree with the answer on practical terms.)

Comment: You said: "If uint8_t exists [...] it's a typedef for [...] (or char if it happens to be unsigned)" which I believe is incorrect. `uint8_t` must be a typedef for an unsigned integer type and `char` is not such type regardless whether it has a sign or not. Similarly, `char` is not a signed integer type. I've debated about this before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16006093/1137388) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16002781/1137388) (read the comments there in). `uint8_t` can be (and probably will but not necessarilly) a typedef for `unsigned char` though.

Comment: The standard does not require short to have 16bits! The standard says: sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long). And sizeof(char) == 1.

Comment: @MFH: The standard says short needs to have a range of at least -32767 to +32767. If you honestly know a way to fit that in fewer than 16 bits, I'd *love* to hear about how it's done.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Care to have a reference for that requirement?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I stand corrected. Your reference did the trick: The C++ Standard does not require that size, but it references §5.2.4.2.1 of the C99 standard in §3.9.1.3 and mandates that those requirements shall be satisfied.