# How to convert nlohmann json to uint8_t array?

Tags: c++, c++11, nlohmann-json

I would like convert my created json object to array of uint8_t[1000]. I tried something like this:

```
    nlohmann::json j_file;
    j_file["number"] = 2;
    j_file["example"] = "dog";

    uint8_t parsed_json[1000] ={0};
    auto str = j_file.dump();
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> v (str.begin(), str.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), parsed_json);
```

but is there an easier way to convert json to uint8_t array?

Comment: A `std::string` is pretty similar to `std::vector<uint8_t>` and can be used in most container algorithms as drop in replacement. Do you really need that conversion?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to buffer overflow.

Comment: What's the purpose of `parsed_json[1000]`? Why not keep it in a `std::string` to not loose the `size()`? `const auto& tmp = j_file.dump(); std::basic_string<unsigned char> str(tmp.data(), std::next(tmp.data(), tmp.size()));` and then you can use `str.data()` to get your `uint8_t*` + you have `str.size()` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy contents of `std::string` to the array without using `std::vector` as proxy.

```
    uint8_t parsed_json[1000] ={0};
    auto str = j_file.dump();
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), parsed_json);
```

Answer (score 1):

Potential XY-problem: Perhaps you don't need to convert to an array at all. You can reinterpret a pointer to the string without copying anything:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned char, std::uint8_t>);
std::uint8_t* parsed_json = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(str.data());
```

Avoiding copying is both more efficient, and will also fix the buffer overflow bug in case the JSON is long.

Comment: this will work in most implementations but is technically undefined behavior as I understand it. Nvm, looks like I am wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260033/reinterpret-cast-between-char-and-stduint8-t-safe

Comment: @PeterT The cast itself is never UB. Techically accessing through the pointer could be UB in theory **if** `std::uint8_t` wasn't an alias of `unsigned char`. But it always is when it is defined at all (in all C++ implementations that I've seen). I've added modification to make sure there is no UB in the example even in such theoretical case.