# Why does int8_t and user input via cin shows strange result

Tags: c++, int, uint8t

A tiny piece of code drives me crazy but hopefully you can prevent me from jumping out of the window. Look here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int8_t i = 65;
    int8_t j;

    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl; // the 'A' is ok, same as uchar

    std::cout << "Now type in a value for j (use 65 again): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> j;
    std::cout << "j = " << j << std::endl;

    if (i != j) 
        std::cout << "What is going on here?????" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "Everything ok." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I use `int` instead of `int8_t` everything ok.  I need this as 8-bit `unsigned integers`, not bigger. And btw. with `unsigned char` it's the same behaviour - of course - as with `int8_t`.

Anyone with a hint?

Comment: `int8_t` can be any 8-bit signed integer type. `char` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int8_t` is a typedef for an integer type with the required characteristics: pure 2's-complement representation, no padding bits, size of exactly 8 bits.

For most (perhaps all) compilers, that means it's going to be a typedef for `signed char`.(Because of a quirk in the definition of the term *signed integer type*, it cannot be a typedef for plain `char`, even if `char` happens to be signed).

The `>>` operator treats character types specially. Reading a character reads a single input character, not sequence of characters representing some integer value in decimal. So if the next input character is `'0'`, the value read will be the *character* value `'0'`, which is probably 48.

Since a `typedef` creates an alias for an existing type, not a new distinct type, there's no way for the `>>` operator to know that you want to treat `int8_t` as an integer type rather than as a character type.

The problem is that in most implementations there is no 8-bit integer type that's not a character type.

The only workaround is to read into an `int` variable and then convert to `int8_t` (with range checks if you need them).

Incidentally, `int8_t` is a *signed* type; the corresponding unsigned type is `uint8_t`, which has a range of 0..255.

(One more consideration: if `CHAR_BIT > 8`, which is permitted by the standard, then neither `int8_t` nor `uint8_t` will be defined at all.)

Comment: It would be nicer, I think, if the `_t` types weren't allowed to `typedef` to `char` (but `unsigned` and `signed` `char` were fine). It would stop this from being implementation-defined.

Comment: @Keith: Thank you for your answer. I will read an int k and cast it: j=(int8_t)k.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: That wouldn't help; `cin >> ...` treats `unsigned char` and `signed char` as character types.

Comment: @Excalibur: There's no need for a cast. Just assign it; the conversion is done implicitly.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh. Well I think that sucks too. `char` is a distinct type entirely because it is supposed to be treated as a special character type.

Comment: @Excalibur: Think about what you want to do if the input is, say, `1000`, which doesn't fit in an `int8_t` or `uint8_t`.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: A substantial body of code needs an unsigned type that is guaranteed to be exactly eight bits with no padding and has the same exemption from aliasing rules as `unsigned char`.  Since `uint8_t` is the only standard-defined type which, if it exists, is guaranteed to be an 8-bit unsigned value with no padding, and since any implementation which would be allowed to define that type would be able to make it use the same aliasing rules as `unsigned char`, a lot of code uses `uint8_t` when it needs a type having both characteristics.

Answer (score 4):

`int8_t` and `uint8_t` are almost certainly character types ([Are int8_t and uint8_t intended to behave like a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911714/are-int8-t-and-uint8-t-intended-to-behave-like-a-character)) so `std::cin >> j` will read a single character from stdin and interpret it as a character, not as a number.

Answer (score 0):

`int8_t` is likely the same as `char`, which means `cin >> j` will simply read a single character (`'6'`) from input and store it in `j`.

Comment: `int8_t` cannot be the same type as `char`. It's most likely the same type as `signed char`.

Answer (score 0):

`int8_t` is defined as a typedef name for `signed char`. So `operator >>` used with an object of type `int8_t` behaves the same way as it would be used for an object of type `signed char`

Comment: It could be a `typedef` for either `signed char` or plain `char`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson No it may not because how type char will behave depends on compiler options. Some compilers by default implement type char as unsigned char.

Comment: Defining `int8_t` as plain `char` is perfectly legal *if* plain `char` is signed. If the signedness of plain `char` depends on a compiler option, the definition of `int8_t` could be controlled by an `#if` test on, for example, `CHAR_MAX`. It's certainly easier to define it as `signed char`, but implementations aren't required to be sensible.

Comment: @Keith Thompson It is a wrong statement. char is not an unsigned integer type while uint8_t shall be defined as unsigned integer type.

Comment: You're right. `char` is an *integer type*, and it's either signed or unsigned, but it's neither a *signed integer type* nor an *unsigned integer type* (a quirk of the way those terms are defined in the C and C++ standards). Conceivably `int8_t` could be a typedef for an *extended signed integer type* (for example, an implementation could define an 8-bit non-character type for just the problem raised in this question). And if `CHAR_BIT > 8`, then `int8_t` will not be defined at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `_t` types aren't first class types, they are `typedef` aliases the observe certain constraints, e.g. `int8_t` is a type that can store a signed, 8-bit value.

On most systems, this will mean they are `typedef`d to `char`. And because they are a typedef and not a first-class type, you are invoking `cin.operator<<(char)` and `cin.operator>>(char)`.

When you input "65", `cin.operator>>(char)` consumes the '6' and places it's ascii value, 54, into variable `j`.

To work around this you'll need to use a different type, possibly the easiest method being just to use a larger integer type and apply constraints and then cast down:

```
int8_t fetchInt8(const char* prompt) {
    int in = 0;
    for ( ; ; ) { // endless loop.
        std::cout << prompt << ": ";
        std::cin >> in;
        if (in >= std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()
              && in <= std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::max()) {
            std::cout << "You entered: " << in << '\n';
            // exit the loop
            break;
        }
        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid number for an int8\n";
    }

    return static_cast<int8_t>(in);
}
```

Note that int8_t is signed, which means it stores -128 thru +127. If you want only positive values, use the uint8_t type.