# 'If' condition not correctly evaluated

Tags: c++

To receive from shell an integer value comprised within the (0, 8) interval, I `cin` to an `uint8_t` element of an array, doing the following:

```
    char answer;

    do
    {
        // Instructions
        std::cout << "Linear actuator resolution is:\n"
                  << "\u0394x = \u03B1r/2^i, with \u03B1 = " << std::to_string(ALPHA)
                  << " degrees, r = " << std::to_string(pulleyR) << " m and i in [0 : 8]\n";

        // Parameter selection
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid value for param 'i': ";
        std::cin >> Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL];
        if(Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL] > (RES_LEVELS - 1))
            // Wrong selection, repeat question
            std::cout << '\r';
        else
        {
            // Print out the selected resolution and ask user to confirm or restart selection
            std::cout << "Selected linear resolution: " << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4)
                      << ALPHA*pulleyR/(1<<Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL])
                      << "m, enter 'y' to confirm, any other key to change selection ";
            std::cin >> answer;
            if(answer == 'y')
                break;
        }
    }while(true);
```

Even though I enter a correct value, the loop does not break.

Entering:

```
std::cout << Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL] << ' ' << (RES_LEVELS - 1) << '\n';
```

in place of:

```
   std::cout << '\r';
```

shell output is:

```
Please enter a valid value for param 'i': 0
0 8
Please enter a valid value for param 'i': 3
3 8
```

which does not make sense.

Comment: Raw and cooked (line-buffered) reads from stdin don't mix well.  You need to either get rid of the `_getch()` call, or get rid of `std::cin` and use only `_getch()`.

Comment: I think, though, that your problem is a misunderstand of exactly where the `continue` keyword jumps to.

Comment: Right, it jumps to the _getch() result evaluation, so the thing can work only if the value is correct at the first round. Nevertheless, if the first value entered is correct, 'continue' should not be reached

Comment: You have a number of questionable things in your code.  One, looping until you press `y` is what this code does, I don't know why that surprises you.  Two, the `std::fixed` and `std::setprecision` modifiers aren't having any effect, because you write a string to the stream, not a number.  Then, what is the value of `RAIL` and how large is the array?  If you access a non-existent element in your array, the program can do very strange things ("undefined behavior").

Comment: RAIL comes from an enum, and is just the '0' index, not exceeding array boundary.

I am not surprised that it loops until 'y' is pressed, I explained that.

Thank you for pointing out the modifiers thing, I am surprised the compiler didn't.

Comment: Are `ALPHA` and `pulleyR` set properly?  Perhaps the compiler is deciding the `else` is illegal and therefore always sending you to the other branch.

Comment: They are just #defines with float value of few digits

Comment: Please also `std::cout << +Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL]` (or cast to `int`).  I suspect you have trigged character-based I/O and your variable holds the ASCII value `'0'` and `'3'` not the numeric value `0` and `3`.

Comment: Also try commenting out the loop, and the else block, and so on, so that your code is as simple as possible to produce the problem.

Comment: Also note that you could have found the problem much much quicker by using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having here is in the way that C++ handles the uint8_t type: it thinks it's a char. If you change your debug output statement to:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL]) << ' ' << (RES_LEVELS - 1) << '\n';
```

you will see that when you type a '0', and ASCII '0' is stored in your uint8_t variable, which has the value 48. Similarly, when you type '3' you're storing a 51, etc.

The simplest solution that will work for you would be to use a character conversion, like this:

```
Engines_uSteppingLevel[RAIL] -= '0';
```

Note that this solution only works for single-digit values. A more robust, extensible solution would involve a std::string or char buffer, and then a call to atoi, strtoul, std::stoul, or something similar.

Comment: It's actually implementation dependent whether `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, or an "extended integral type".  The simplest solution is to read into a numeric variable, validate the value, then store it into the array.

Comment: This answer provides a great analysis of how `(u)int8_t` can map to different extraction operators on different platforms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16006093/103167