# Create custom compiler warning when using e.g. int8_t

Tags: c++

Im trying to get something like 'custom-made' compiler warnings when the user uses variable types like int8_t which could result in unwanted behaviour ([Are int8_t and uint8_t intended to be char types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911714/are-int8-t-and-uint8-t-intended-to-be-char-types)).

Therefore I'd like to (optionally) replace these variable types and append a warning **when** they are used. My idea so far is something like this:

*header.h*

```
#pragma once

#pragma warning ("int8_t can be interpreted as char - replaced with int16_t")
#define int8_t int16_t
```

But this will not print the custom error msg, neither will it print it for each replacement but instead always print once, whether int8_t was replaced or not.

If you have any suggestions how to tackle this problem I would gladly appreciate any help!

Comment: `#define int8_t int16_t` No. Don't.

Comment: I suppose the easy way is to have a script (run in CMake or a job in your CI system) that will just grep through modified files and print that "warning" and perhaps do something else (stop compilation?). But don't do a macro substitution. Let developer consider the risks on their own and either ignore the warning or change the type to `char` or `int16_t` themselves.

Comment: This is going to depend on the features of your specific compiler, so you'll need to say what compiler you are using.  For gcc, the `deprecated` type attribute may be useful.